# Installing Ubuntu on a chiliGREEN E-Board MX500

Tags: boot, uefi, tablet

Once upon a time I bought a cheap tablet so I could be more productive. But for I'm a student and have no money to spare for fancy Surfaces I went in the woods, aka a local manufacturer called chiliGREEN, and bought one of theirs.

But then evil Windows turned up. Slowing my poor new friend down, even nearly rendering it useless, because Windows suddenly uses nearly all space available. 
That's when a promising saviour turned up: Linux.

On to a more serious tone:
I would like to get Ubuntu on my System, but problems emerged.

First, here is the (german) product homepage:

http://www.chiligreen.com/shop/configurator.asp?typ=299&serie=557&id=13531

Many tiny problems I could already solve, like getting a USB Hub to work or finding a 32bit UEFI file to be able to boot.

But currently I am stuck. Right after the EFI menu, either by trying without installing or getting straight to installation, the device goes black screen. Even the mouse and keyboard are turned off for some odd reason. All I can do at this point is force a shutdown by pressing the power button for 5 seconds.

As I am more of a Ubuntu/Linux noob I can not figure out what's wrong, not to mention knowing what magic words I have to put in the command line to fix the problem.

I would be very glad to get some advice on how to find out what is not working. Solutions are even more welcomed :D

Thanks in advance for all answers!